# Display only first element of each category

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my code, there are list items and they all have a category. Each categories are sequentially added for each list items.

Here is my HTML:

**HTML**

```
<ul>

  <li class='A'>A1</li>
  <li class='A'>A2</li>
  <li class='A'>A3</li>
  <li class='A'>A4</li>

  <li class='B'>B1</li>
  <li class='B'>B2</li>
  <li class='B'>B3</li>
  <li class='B'>B4</li>

  <li class='C'>C1</li>
  <li class='C'>C2</li>
  <li class='C'>C3</li>
  <li class='C'>C4</li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li{display:none}
ul li.A:nth-of-type(1){display:block}
ul li.B:nth-of-type(1){display:block}
ul li.C:nth-of-type(1){display:block}
```

I am trying to display only the first element of each category. I am expecting below output:

- A1
- B1
- C1

Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9pdby6st/200/

I observed that nth-of-type works only when the very first element is that category.

Here are the limitations:

- Cannot change html structure
- Cannot use javascript

Can use SCSS. Any advice?

Comment: ul li:nth-child(4n+1){display:block}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the adjacent sibling selector `+`  for the elements that end with a class name and start the next tag with another class name.

Eg: `.A + .B {display: block}`

In the above case, only one instance is possible and the first element with the classname `B` displays and the other siblings are hidden.

You could use it to create many combos such as `.B + .C {display: block}` and so on.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/9pdby6st/202/)

```css
ul li {
  display: none
}

ul li.A:first-child {
  display: block
}

ul li.A+.B {
  display: block
}

ul li.B+.C {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li class='A'>A1</li>
  <li class='A'>A2</li>
  <li class='A'>A3</li>
  <li class='A'>A4</li>

  <li class='B'>B1</li>
  <li class='B'>B2</li>
  <li class='B'>B3</li>
  <li class='B'>B4</li>

  <li class='C'>C1</li>
  <li class='C'>C2</li>
  <li class='C'>C3</li>
  <li class='C'>C4</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Would be better to use display: list-item instead of block to keep the items looking like list-items.

Answer (score 2):

As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1423096

You can set the property for all the items and then undo it for the siblings that come after the first one.

```css
ul li {
  color: red
}

ul li.A:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: blue
}

ul>li.B {
  color: green
}

ul>li.B~li.B {
  color: red
}

ul>li.C {
  color: yellow
}

ul>li.C~li.C {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li class='A'>A1</li>
  <li class='A'>A2</li>
  <li class='A'>A3</li>
  <li class='A'>A4</li>

  <li class='B'>B1</li>
  <li class='B'>B2</li>
  <li class='B'>B3</li>
  <li class='B'>B4</li>

  <li class='C'>C1</li>
  <li class='C'>C2</li>
  <li class='C'>C3</li>
  <li class='C'>C4</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (inspired by [alo Malbarez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880442/860099))

```css
ul li{display:block}
ul>li.A~li.A {display: none}
ul>li.B~li.B {display: none}
ul>li.C~li.C {display: none}
```

```html
<ul>
    
  <li class='A'>A1</li>
  <li class='A'>A2</li>
  <li class='A'>A3</li>
  <li class='A'>A4</li>
  
  <li class='B'>B1</li>
  <li class='B'>B2</li>
  <li class='B'>B3</li>
  <li class='B'>B4</li>
  
  <li class='C'>C1</li>
  <li class='C'>C2</li>
  <li class='C'>C3</li>
  <li class='C'>C4</li>

</ul>
```